# Probability of India scoring at least $7$ in the Test Cricket Series.

Tags: probability, proof-verification

> India plays two matches each with West Indies and Australia. In any match the probabilities of India
>   getting points $0, 1$ and $2$ are $0.45, 0.05$ and $0.50$ respectively. Assuming that the outcomes are
>   independent, the probability of India getting at least $7$ points is
>
> $(1)\  0.8750 \ \ \ (2)\  0.0875\  \ \ (3)\  0.0625\  \ \ (4)\  0.0250$

I am not asking for the result . Just check if my method is correct .

$$P(\mathrm{India\; getting\; at\; least\; 7})=1-[P(\mathrm{India\; getting\; 0})+P(\mathrm{India\; getting \;1})+P(\mathrm{India\; getting\; 2})+\cdots + P(\mathrm{India\; getting\; 6})]\tag{*}$$

The cases of getting points less than $7$  are as follows

> $$\mathrm{case\; 0:\ \ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0\\case\; 1:\ \ \ 1\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0\\case\; 2:\ \ \ 1\ \ 1\ \ 0\ \ 0\\case\; 2:\ \ \ 2\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0\\case\; 3:\ \ \ 1\ \ 1\ \ 1\ \ 0\\case\; 3:\ \ \ 1\ \ 2\ \ 0\ \ 0\\case\; 4:\ \ \ 1\ \ 1\ \ 2\ \ 0\\case\; 4:\ \ \ 2\ \ 2\ \ 0\ \ 0\\case\; 4:\ \ \ 1\ \ 1\ \ 1\ \ 1\\case\; 5:\ \ \ 2\ \ 2\ \ 1\ \ 0\\case\; 5:\ \ \ 2\ \ 1\ \ 1\ \ 1\\case\; 6:\ \ \ 1\ \ 1\ \ 2\ \ 2\\case\; 6:\ \ \ 2\ \ 2\ \ 2\ \ 0}$$

Since the outcomes are independent , the Probability of $(\mathrm{case} )$ is $(0.45)^4$ , $\mathrm{case \;1}$ is $(0.45)^3\times 0.05$ ; $case\; 2$ is $[(0.45)^2\times (0.05)^2 + 0.50\times (0.45)^3]$   and so on and for $\mathrm{case\; 6}$ the probability is $[0.45\times (0.50)^3 + (0.50)^2\times (0.05)^2].$ Thus after calculating all the cases I just have to  work out the formula in  $(*)$  and the result  is it . Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

That is correct, but the easier way is to just count the ways in which $7$ or more points can be achieved. $8$ is achieved only when each match gives $2$ points. The probability of this is $(0.5)^4 = 0.0625$. 7 is achieved with 3 wins and a draw, whose probability is $(0.5)^3(0.05)$ and can be achieved in 4 different ways. Thus the probability you are looking for is
$$
(0.5)^4 + 4(0.5)^3(0.05)
$$

Comment: but why 7 isnt possible 3 wins 1 draw you get 7

Comment: Oh of course. Let me fix that.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. You applied:
$$ \mathbb{P}[\text{India gets 7 or more points}] = \sum_{k \geq 7} \mathbb{P}[\text{India gets } k \text{ points}] $$

It is easy to see that the probabilities for $k \geq 9$ are all zero, so we have:
$$ \mathbb{P}[\text{India gets 7 or more points}] = \mathbb{P}[\text{India gets 7 points}] + \mathbb{P}[\text{India gets 8 points}] $$

India can only score 8 points by scoring 2 points in all four matches, so $\mathbb{P}[\text{India gets 8 points}] = 0.5^4 = 0.0625$. Now, for $k = 7$ it is useful to apply some (very simple) combinatorics. We see that in order for India to score a total of 7 points, it needs to score 2 points in three matches and 1 point in one. There are 4 different possible permutations in which India scores a total of 7 points (possibility 1: India scores 1 in the first match, 2 in the rest, possibility 2: India scores 1 in the second match, 2 in the rest, etc...). So we see that the probability of India scoring a total of 7 points is $ 4 \cdot 0.05 \cdot 0.5^3 = 0.025$.

So the probability that India scores a total of 7 points is $ 0.0625 + 0.025 = 0.0875 $.